# Rolling Upgrade Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, hortonworks-data-platform

I work in a big telecom shop. One of main Hadoop clusters (HDP) has about 600 nodes. It upgrades almost monthly plus some other maintenance.  Every time doing so takes hours to a couple of days and all apps running on it have to be shut off.  I just cannot imagine the clusters performing such important work in other companies will get interrupted so often and so long. I asked why don't we do rolling upgrade? Here is one of main architect's answer.  Is it true? How about the upgrades in your company?

> Regarding rolling upgrades, I want to be careful that everyone
>   understand what happens during this process. Up to 12 nodes per hour
>   get upgraded to the next version of HDP. As this process continues
>   with each passing hour the capacity of the cluster is reduced by X
>   number of nodes that get completed. When the cluster gets in the
>   neighborhood of 75% a restart is required for most of the services.
>   The core services are handled under the up-time such as MapReduce,
>   HDFS, Name Node HA, Resource Manager HA, Zookeeper and Hive HA if it
>   is configured. Spark, Kafka, Storm and the other services are not
>   included in Rolling upgrade with no downtime. Express upgrade has
>   allowed our team to upgrade the clusters in a much faster timeframe.
>   The last upgrade of the cluster was 5 hours. I believe the issue of
>   downtime you stated above with 2 days and 4 hours would not be correct
>   for the actual HDP downtime. This is likely the entire maintenance
>   which would include Ambari Upgrades, HDP upgrades, stopping jobs,
>   sanity checks, and restarting all of the jobs to complete catch up
>   with batch processing. I would like to suggest that your team is
>   engaged with the messages that will be sent out and stop your job at
>   the time the upgrade will be executing which would be on Saturday
>   morning. When the upgrade is completed you will be able to start your
>   job again, another notification will be sent out.